# Is there anything more efficient than ToArray (or ToList) to lock in an enumerable set?

Tags: .net, memory-management

Suppose I have 100,000 items in a `HashSet<Task>`.
I need to construct an `IEnumerable<Task>` of the N tasks in the HashSet which are completed, in preparation to remove them from the HashSet. I will not be using TrimExcess once removed, because I want the capacity to remain high.

First, the IEnumerable of completed tasks is defined as `HashSet<Task>.Where(x => x.IsCompleted)`.

Obviously, I cannot simply iterate over that enumerable to remove the items, because the underlying collection will be modified and the enumerator will throw an exception. Ultimately, I need to get this into an `Task[]` to pass to `Task.WaitAll` to ensure the results are observed.

(Too bad the framework has no `WaitAll` overloads that accept an IEnumerable instead of an array. By the way, the call to `WaitAll` should be a quick, efficient call from looking at its implementation. Because all the Tasks are already completed, it never even initializes any internal list of Tasks to wait on. Clever.)

I could be lazy and just call `ToArray` on the enumerable, but from what I understand, that not only uses a `List` internally (which has to perform size-doubling memory allocations as it's built), but the conversion to an Array type requires it to do one extra allocation/copy to ensure the underlying buffer is exactly sized).

Is there something more efficient than `ToArray` or `ToList` which, for example, will allocate disjoint, constant-sized blocks of memory as neeeded (presumably this would be more efficiently than doubling the size and copying the whole list every time it's capacity changes). I'm thinking of something more linear, like allocate capacity for 100 items at a time, such that when finished, I can iterate over the disjoint blocks to just do a single copy into an array just once. Maybe I'm overthinking this, but this is performance-critical code I'm working on. Alternatively, I could do the enumeration twice... once to determine the exact size required of the final array, and then again to copy the items. This may all depend on the relative expense of checking IsCompleted multiple times vs doing all those memory allocations and copies.

Comment: Use [RemoveWhere()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.removewhere).

Comment: RemoveWhere could help, although I'd still have to do the "observation" in the predicate. Still interested in whether there's a more memory and processor friendly way to lock in an enumerable set. The 'double size and copy' that's standard seems like it's allocating extra memory unnecessarily in some situations as well as doing lots of unnecessary copying every time. I just learned of the ArrayBuffer class, so I may use that.